# Quire webhooks API

Tags: quire-api

I have difficult to understand how webooks works. From documentation (https://quire.io/dev/api/#webhook) there is a section about Notification, and so:

"If the app wants to receive notifications of a specific projects or tasks, it can follow the projects or apps by sending a PUT request to the URL. To add a follower, the body of the request can be"

First question: Where should i send the put request?

What i want to do is to send task creation (and edit) on a specific nodejs server (listening over https). I have added my server url to "webhook" section in my app settings.

Second question: If above step is correct, what are the next steps?

Thansk, Nicola

Answer (score 0):

1) the PUT request is sent to the resource you want to follow:

e.g. to follow an existing task you have to [update a task](https://quire.io/dev/api/#operation--task--oid--put) using the `addFollowers` parameter

Four your case you'd have to [follow a Project](https://quire.io/dev/api/#operation--project--oid--put) and see filter the notifications are posted to your webhook endpoint.
More detail was given in this [duplicate question in github](https://github.com/quire-api/quire-api/issues/35)

2) next steps would be to implement your webhook endpoint and listen to notifications.